# Change windows XP password via (2nd) remote desktop

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, passwords

I'd like to change my Win XP workstation password from home, but I've got to do it via Remote Desktop connection (from home, and it's my  work machine).

The problem is, that I make the connection via another windows machine.... so

HOME MACHINE -> MIDDLE SERVER -> WORKSTATION

Now if I hit `CTRL+ALT+DEL` (while logged in to WORKSTATION), I have access to my home machine password change function (which is normal). If I hit `CTRL+ALT+END` (as that is the shortcut for Remote Desktop's task manager), I have access to the middle server's password change function.

(Using the below mentioned control panel solution doesn't work, see my comment on that.)

But how can I reach the workstation's change password function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I'm no more using XP since long time, but do

```
Control Panel > User and account > Change my password
```

Would work?

Comment: Nope, I'm part of a domain, so it says I should hit CTRL+ALT+DELETE.

Answer (score 2):

Through remote desktop you must use CTRL + ALT + END to change your password remotely.

EDIT: see my correction below (2nd comment)

2nd edit: [Here is a solution that should work, finally :)](https://serverfault.com/a/359992/56270)
Note that the comments on the question specify that what you have to do is pressing `CTRL` and `ALT` locally and then clicking the `DEL` key on the virtual keyboard.

Comment: But that's brings up the middle servers' task manager/password change function (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: My bad I wanted to say CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + END which, if I remember correctly, should work.

Comment: It does not work :-( (I'm on a Lenovo 3000 N200 which has no END only key, but with a "Fn" key. So I had pressed "CTRTL ALT SHIFT FN END", without luck.

Answer (score 1):

RDP into the MIDDLE SERVER, then into WORKSTATION. Minimize the WORKSTATION and bring up the on screen keyboard using "ease of access".  Make sure it is set to "always on top".  Now maximize your WORKSTATION and hit ctrl-alt-end on the on-screen keyboard from MIDDLE SERVER.  This should bring up the option screen where you can click on change password

Comment: This was going to be my answer. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are an administrator on the network, you can just do it at a command prompt:

net user user_name new_password

I tested this...will add more if I can find a way to do it for domain non-administrative users.

Just another point, which may not help you, but if you have access to Outlook Web Access 2010 (2007 if your administrator made special modifications), you can change your password in the options.

P.S. I came across this: This is pretty cool for just locking the workstation: rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

Note: Comments below were in response to my initial answer, which has been changed.

Comment: That did not work :-(